# "Socket error on client..., disconnecting" when Mosquitto brigde to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, mosquitto

I have installed two broker of Mosquitto (1.4.2-3.2x86_64)and RabbitMQ (3.5.3-1) using newest version so far on CentOS 6 servers. With default configuration i can sub/pub messages for each broker separately, this mean that MQTT is running normally.
But when i bridge Mosquitto server to a RabbitMQ server, i face below problem right after i change mosquitto.conf file: 
**"Connecting bridge (Rabbit-IP)**

**Socket error on client *client_name*, disconnecting".**

My bridge configuration in mosquitto.conf is:

**connection *test***

**address *Rabbitmq-IP***

**topic # both 0 *local/ remote/***

Can you explain to me !
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this option in your config file for the bridge

```
try_private false
```

This is an option that will tell the other broker that this is a bridge connection and defaults to true and if the RabbitMQ doesn't supports it, then it would not allow you to connect.

Comment: Thanks Luis, I gave it a try but the error remain !